# Injected DLL is immediately unloaded

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, dll-injection

I'm using `C++` to inject a DLL into a running process. A great source code base for this is [here](https://github.com/OpenSecurityResearch/dllinjector) (it's the one I'm using). For a short example, you may use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372524) question. My problem is that after injection, the `DLL` is immediately unloaded again. I can observe loaded `DLL`s in [`x64Dbg`](https://x64dbg.com) for instance when the debugger is attached and it said the following:

```
Thread 7CC8 created, Entry: <kernel32.LoadLibraryA>
DLL Loaded: 0000000001110000 D:\MyDLL.dll
DLL Unloaded: 0000000001110000 mydll.dll
Thread 7CC8 exit
```

I debugged the injection and it always happened on `CreateRemoteThread()` or a similar method of setting up and running the thread.

Why is this happening and how to prevent the process from unloading the `DLL`? I've seen comments like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436845/3764804) suggesting to use [`GetModuleHandleEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683200(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm not sure where to use it in the code and how. When finding the address of `LoadLibrary` in the target process or does it need to be called in the injected `DLL`? How would the method call look like then?

```
loadLibAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "LoadLibraryA");
```

[Another suggestion was to repeatedly call `LoadLibrary`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454333/3764804) but when exactly? The process already unloaded the `DLL` after the thread creation so I'm not sure how this could be done.

[`Reflective injection`](https://github.com/stephenfewer/ReflectiveDLLInjection) does not work (e.g. `GetReflectiveLoaderOffset()` returns `0`). I'm also working with entirely `64-bit` applications.

I know this is possible since I've seen a persistent injection happen by another application.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: One thing that I already detected is that you are using the address of `LoadLibraryA` from your current process rather than the remote one, they are not the same.

Comment: There are much easier ways of injecting DLLs if you ask me, take a look at `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: @Havenard: I'm using pretty much exactly the code from the `GitHub` repository https://github.com/OpenSecurityResearch/dllinjector since it is very configurable.

Comment: I don't do Windows, but ... is your `DllMain` or whatever returning or something like that?

Comment: @o11c: Yes, it installs some hooks and then returns successfully. It's meant to do that but I'm still wondering why it gets unloaded and the hooks are also not in effect then.

Comment: I suspect it was never really loaded, would have to analyze the relevant parts of the code. Either LoadLibrary fails or FreeLibrary is called, and it surely doesn't call itself.

Comment: Maybe DllMain returns something it shouldn't? I don't remember if it matters but it's worth taking a look.